# jquery timepicker not putting data into input in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, timepicker

I have a jqgrid where I'm displaying start and end time. I have included a jquery plugin for time picker. However, when I submit my form the data for both times is missing. I believe the date for the times chosen is not being added to the input field before submitting. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

I'm using jquery plugin by perifer: http://labs.perifer.se/timedatepicker/

Below is how I've wrote the function.

```
function addDayAndTimeRow(){
                    $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", 
                        { url: '<c:url value="/dayandtimes/create/"/>'+row_id,
                            beforeShowForm: function(form) {
                                $('#starttime').timepicker();
                                $('#endtime').timepicker();
                            },
                            closeAfterAdd: true,
                            bottominfo: "Fields marked with (*) are required"
                        }
                    );
                }
```

Comment: not without some code... if you choose a time in timepicker (which one you using?) the input value should update and if you submit it right you will get your data for sure

Comment: I'm using timepicker by perifer. http://labs.perifer.se/timedatepicker/

Comment: I've updated the question. Can you tell me if i"m missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

check your input name="" attributes and your requests in php. as this timepicker just writes a new value into the input field (attribute value="") there must be a small problem on your side.

inspect your DOM after selected start and end time if the value of the input is updated. if, then the timepicker plugin is OK

Comment: I think everything is OK on my end as I have tried manually typing in the time and the form submits then.

Comment: check the plugin again.. does the value change in DOM after selecting start and end time?